# Why don't publication venues systematically make the LaTeX source of papers available?

Tags: publications, open-science, latex

I wonder why most publication venues don't systematically make the LaTeX source for published papers available? (which implies systematically asking authors for the LaTex source)

LaTex source are more machine readable than PDFs, and make it easier for humans to reuse part of it (e.g. math equation or figures), amongst other advantages. I fail to see any downside.

(I am aware that some authors write their publications using other tools such as Microsoft Word: let's ignore it.)

Comment: I've worked with people who sent me LaTeX code for drafts that did not even properly compile, although the pdf looked ok… BibTeX files were sometimes even worse…

Comment: Commercial publishers such as Elsevier and Springer are not part of academia, and they don't share their culture of openness. Very far from it. They consider the final TeX code and their mix of classes and packages as a trade secret.

Comment: Many figures are submitted as separate files and access to the LaTeX won't help at all since that only contains a link.

Comment: @Pharap Being able to type a sentence in google and see the papers it comes up with is immensely helpful, for starters... (Yes, that's possible with PDFs too, but it's an example of "a machine reading a paper".)

Comment: @Pharap I'm answering your question *Why would one want a machine to read a paper?* and I already mention in my comment that PDFs can be searched. It's not quite clear what conclusion you're trying to reach, and since you've already started to move goalposts I don't think I want to participate.

Comment: Reclarifying old question: Why would LaTeX being *more* machine readable than a PDF be an advantage? (Other than being able to extract equations from it, which I expect is also possible with PDF).

Comment: What matters is the content of a paper. So the pdf is kind of the black box that hides what lead to the binary decision of pixel or no pixel. Some people use code that should better be hidden in a closet than made publicly available, just as @Dirk mentioned. Also, the big publishers use LaTeX in a way you are not expecting it.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni it's not a "trade secret", if anything they legally own the text and figures. Besides, professional publishers typically use commercial software for typesetting, and often re-type articles entirely. There is no Latex source to share. It's much more efficient than dealing with everyone's pet Latex package mix.

Comment: @Pharap E.g. extracting information from a table is typically much easier when the table is in LaTeX than when it is in PDF. Also, my experience with PDF->LaTeX conversion for equations is not so good, and it's one more tool to use..

Comment: Searching text is not easier with LaTex or such. Even in StackExchange formulas are discouraged in titles as they confuse the search engine.

Comment: @Greg machine readability != searchability.

Comment: pdf is a binary format. This is like asking for a tool that gives the code base of Microsoft word. Once you cooked up the stew, it is extremely difficult to know all the detailed ingridients.

Comment: God bless whoever opens my LaTeX file... I just patch things here and there to achieve a certain effect and it's like a space shuttle launching platform supported by recycled cardboard, duct tapes, and popsicle sticks.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight You seem to be the rigt person to drop in the TeX.SX chat once in a while :-)

Comment: @Penguin_Knight: I just joined this community in order to +1 your comment. `:)`

Comment: @Johannes: do not tell there are ducks around academia too. `:)`

Comment: If I was asked to provide the LaTeX file, I would be very concerned with cleaning up the code and removing all the commented text that was either rewritten or just notes to myself. I am happy the venues I submit to don't ask for it.. Maybe the organizers think the same?

Comment: @MohamedKhamis You can easily remove all comments with a script (the publication venues could take care of it).

Answer (score 32):

I suspect that this is a solution in search of a problem. Most likely journals aren't making LaTeX versions of papers available because they don't see a demand for such a service from the side of the readers; this would take effort to implement and maintain; and some authors would object to the idea of making it easier for others to reuse (read: plagiarize) their papers. In other words, publishers simply have (or at least think they have) better things to do with their time and money.

It should be noted that arXiv *does* make LaTeX source code available, and in fact will only accept submissions in the original source code rather than as PDFs (for papers that were written in LaTeX), so in those areas of math and physics where uploading preprint versions of one's paper to arXiv is the norm, this "problem" (such that it is) is already solved.

Comment: +1 I think this is the major point.  PDFs are quite sufficiently machine-readable for purposes of search engines, and unless people are clamoring for LaTeX source, they'll focus their resources on the things that people *are* clamoring for, like better per-paper metrics.

Comment: I guess it's a bit like binaries and source code: binaries are enough for most situations, but if one day one needs the source code while only binaries are available, problems arise (-> PDFBox).

Answer (score 25):

I think your question is actually about why publishers don't make the LaTeX source of papers available to readers rather than why publishers don't accept submissions in LaTeX form.  You might want to clarify your question.

Some publishers prefer to accept PDF versions of paper for review, but then ask for LaTeX source code after the paper has been accepted.  Doing the peer review process with a PDF version of the paper saves the publisher the trouble of running the paper through LaTeX and fixing any problems that the authors might inadvertently have introduced into the manuscript (such as using non-standard packages of macros.)

At the final publication stage, authors typically submit LaTeX source to journals.  The journal then applies its own style to the paper, adds copyright notices and page numbers, and produces a final version of the paper using LaTeX.  However, journals typically only publish PDF versions of the papers rather than the LaTeX source.

Many journals make their style files available to authors and ask them to prepare the manuscript using the journal's style.  This helps to avoid problems when the final version of the paper is prepared by the publisher.

Having the LaTeX source of a paper makes it slightly easier for plagiarists to cut and paste mathematical formulas and text from the paper or to maliciously produce alternate versions of the paper. Commercial publishers are also generally opposed to any use of a paper that goes beyond simply reading the paper- making LaTeX source available tends to make such reuse easier.

Comment: +1 Excellent point about how providing "LaTeX source of a paper makes it slightly easier for plagiarists".

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure that journal publishers do "produce a final version of the paper using LaTeX." My understanding is that the large publishers use their own in-house systems for final publication and that, while LaTeX is clearly an input to that, the final work is not done using LaTeX but with some other proprietary software.

Comment: I can more or less confirm what @DavidRicherby said in at least one case: when submitting to the American Physical Society journals, I am told as part of the publication process that the submitted paper will be converted into their proprietary XML format.

Comment: Clearly, my answer is only applicable to those publishers who produce final versions of papers using LaTeX.  In my experience that includes Elsevier, SIAM, and INFORMS.  This is getting a bit beyond the original question though...

Comment: @DavidRicherby are you suggesting that there is proprietary software out there that duplicates the functionality of TeX and LaTeX without using the original TeX/LaTeX engines at some point during the compilation? If that's what you're saying, I'm willing to bet money that that's incorrect. (And if that's not what you're saying, then I'm not sure what you mean by "I'm not sure that journal publishers do 'produce a final version...using LaTeX'".)

Comment: @DanRomik As I said, "LaTeX is clearly an input". However, my understanding is that producing an issue of a journal or volume of conference proceedings does not necessarily involve producing a big .tex file, running pdflatex on it and sending the resulting .pdf file to the printing company. I don't know what other steps there are, whether they involve massaging the .tex, the .pdf or something else, but I'm pretty sure they exist (I'm pretty sure I remember reading author instructions that say that even using the supplied LaTeX style file only produces an approximation of the final output.

Comment: @DanRomik This [post on TeX.se](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99123/46235) talks about software used by some typesetting companies, though some of the comments to the answer dispute its claims.

Comment: @DavidZ, American Institute of Physics similarly (in fact I *think* it's the same software)

Comment: @DavidRicherby LaTeX being an input does not say anything about whether the TeX/LaTeX engines are used. I claim that (in the context of academic publication of papers in CS/math/physics) all publishers will in fact use those engines (or possibly use PDF directly generated by the authors). They may have some complicated workflow involving layers of proprietary software, but at some point, code written by Knuth/Lamport/etc. will be run. So your statement "I'm not sure...using LaTeX" seems to me like it was phrased in a misleading way, given that apparently you meant something subtly different.

Comment: @DanRomik I'm sorry you felt I was being misleading but I think what I've written is an accurate summary of my admittedly vague beliefs on this subject. The relatively large number of upvotes my comment received and the confirmatory comments by Chris H suggest that other people believe that what I said is some kind of approximation to the truth.

Comment: @DavidRicherby okay, I'll bow to the wisdom of the crowd then and admit that I was being silly. It does happen from time to time.

Comment: @DanRomik The use of XML as an intermediate step by APS is very clearly documented; indeed, it's the very first line of the [APS guide to REVTeX 4.1](https://d22izw7byeupn1.cloudfront.net/files/revtex/apsguide4-1.pdf). Their system obviously uses some form of the (La)TeX stack at some point of the process (they explicitly ask for REVTeX source files), but a tex->xml->pdf workflow is nonstandard in terms of what an author might do. §II of the guide explicitly says that the REVTeX output is only an approximation to the final pdf produced via the XML, which also produces the HTML output.

Comment: @E.P. that's interesting. I understand and agree that there are some nonstandard LaTeX-based workflows around. However given the above discussion and the votes on Davis Richerby's comment it seems that your "obviously" may not be so obvious to everyone. Thanks for helping to clarify the situation.

Comment: I have been told by insiders at IEEE that they do not actually use LaTeX to typeset papers. Instead "some proprietary software" takes the LaTeX source as input, translates it to some intermediate XML format and produces the final output from that.

I guess the point about using or not using LaTeX to typeset LaTeX documents is that many publishers generally do not *only* use LaTeX to do it. Consequently, the final output may not be exactly reproducible by outsiders (such as the authors themselves) using *only* freely available software such as LaTeX.

Comment: [Related question on TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120496), with another claim that APS journals use Advanced Print Publisher.

Answer (score 11):

Those publication venues that have use for the code typically ask for it (e.g., EPTCS). But if a publication venue does not need the source, why should they ask for that?

While in principle, LaTeX source code may look more readable than PDFs, there are many limitations to LaTeX source code. Those who ever tried to use a LaTeX2HTML converter know what I mean. As an example, there are documents that will compile with XeLaTeX, but not with LuaLaTex ... and vice versa! Furthermore, there are documents that will only work with the latest TikZ version. Then, there are documents that do not compile anymore with modern LaTeX distributions. So reusing LaTeX code later may need manual work to make the code work with modern TeX distributions.

But also applications that make use of TeX code snippets are hard to do based on author-supplied TeX code. Copying a figure is difficult as the needed macros may be scattered through the complete document. Also, the figure code may depend on packages that can clash with other packages, which makes pasting them elsewhere difficult as well. Furthermore, searching in TeX code is difficult (which would be another application for which the source code could be used), as heavy use of macros may lead to the search term not being shown in the actual code. Both of these issues do not exist with the later PDF.

Comment: "If a publication venue does not need the source, why should they ask for that?" -> to allow machine readable access, and make it easier for humans to reuse part of articles (e.g. math equation or figures). In these two use cases, most of the time there is no need to compile the LaTeX document.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I added a paragraph discussing that.

Answer (score 5):

A substantial number of all-OA publishers *do* offer machine-readable versions of papers - they just do so as XML rather than as LaTeX. See, for example, the XML links on these papers in various journals:

- [Cryosphere (EGU)](http://www.the-cryosphere.net/9/2417/2015/tc-9-2417-2015.html)
- [PLOS One (PLOS)](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0145904)
- [Journal of Economic Structures (SpringerOpen)](http://www.journalofeconomicstructures.com/content/5/1/2)
- [Remote Sensing (MDPI)](http://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/8/1/32)

As the XML is probably more machine-readable than the LaTeX source, why go to the extra effort of providing an intermediate format - especially one with all the reuse/interpretation problems that DCT & others refer to?

Comment: Many journals convert LaTeX to XML, thus the XML is the intermediate format.

Comment: @ChrisH surely the XML is (one of two) final formats, rather than an intermediate one, in these cases?

Answer (score 1):

LaTeX files are *less* searchable than PDF and are almost always useless on their own.

Next to the packages problem already mentioned here LaTeX files often use a lot of other files as input, which makes redistribution a hassle. This also makes the file less machine readable. A search engine such as Google will not understand where a given image, or other other input file will appear in the text and thus will not link the two, hurting the context and search results the file is placed in. This is not the case with PDF files where everything is grouped together (or at least understood where it should be placed, see the HTML view Google makes of PDF files).

Now one could argue that you should publish all files required to build the LaTeX file. But even in my extremely limited academic experience I have found cases where this is impossible. Some tables in my thesis were generated by LaTeX using 500MB of raw data. It would be crazy to have to distribute these (or for a machine to need to parse these).

Comment: You get into open-data question rather quickly if the LaTeX is interpreting your files to build the tables (though that is probably rather rare in papers if they're compiled at the journal).

Comment: The opposite case is argued quite eloquently in arXiv's [Why Submit the TeX/LaTeX Source?](https://arxiv.org/help/faq/whytex) piece.

Comment: @E.P. that piece does not address any of the context issues with linked content I speak of or any issues with large input files :).